# Apache Airflow: How to trigger multiple DAGs dynamically?

Tags: python, airflow

I have 2 DAGs: 
1. DAG1 - runner
2. DAG2 - pipeline

I need to fetch some JSON endpoint in DAG1, get an array of N items `response.data.items`, and trigger DAG2 per every item with passed `item.somedata`

How to do that?

upd. I tried

```
dag = DAG(
    'fetch-1',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Fetching emails',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)

t1 = DummyOperator(
  task_id='start',
  dag=dag,
)

r = requests.post('http://host.docker.internal:8080/fetch-emails')
j = r.json()


for _, msg in j.data.messages:
  tx = DummyOperator(
    task_id='email_pipeline_{}'.format(msg.id),
    dag=dag,
  )
  t1 >> tx
```

Comment: I'm not sure my code makes any sense, but added

Comment: by DAG  you mean directed acycclic graph? or is it some docker thing?

Comment: I'm sure you cannot do that. You cannot add tasks dynamically as the way you want.

Comment: right, directed acyclic graph, it's tagged with airflow

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to both run a dag while using intermediate results from that dag to create itself. this is impossible.

instead what you can do is, from dag1, trigger multiple dag2 runs using the `dag_runs` endpoint as described [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/rest-api-ref.html).

Comment: nice point, but I want to keep control of all subdags, like treeview, etc. Is that possible with triggering by HTTP?

Comment: i guess you could conceivably create a dag with `n` subdags where `n` is way more than you think you'd ever need, have your first task output all its data into a queue, and have each of the subdags grab a piece to process. but i don't think that's a great idea, it would just fit what you want.